# following iterative and agile in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, deployment, webforms, iteration

ok, i know there are a lot of posts online that specify how to do iterations with MVC.

my question is slightly different. when i used to do iterations using WebForms, i was creating one thing only and finishing that one thing till the end which was including the deployment on production.
for example, i was creating a webpage and deploying it, then i create the second page and deploy it. so .dll files were added to my bin folder while the previous dlls remain untouched. at the other hand, when i was making a change latter on, there was this one file that needed to be replaced on production.

now here is the question, how can i acheive the same thing in mvc? beause it just doesn't deploy each page into an individual dll. each time that i add something i have to redeploy the application dll which is not really wise! i played around with deployment options in visual studio but no luck!

Comment: The title of your post references Agile and Iterations but your question really seems to be centered on a deployment question -- just sayin'.

Comment: well i think they're related! if i can not deploy my stand alone iteration then Mvc can't really be used for itrations, unless you do all of iterations and when everything is ready just deploy once. if that is the case then doing iterations with mvc is for ENTERPRISE use only and not small or mid-level solutions.

Comment: Why would it be 'unwise' to redeploy the application assembly?

Comment: each time u add something, the size of that assembly grows. imagine an enterprise app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from putting controllers and other code in separate assemblies and dropping them in an existing application. Like any ASP.NET based application an MVC application will automatically restart if you add or modify any file in the bin folder or modify web.config.

If you're using Razor you can use [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) to generate code for your views and compile them into the same assembly.

You may need to write some additional logic though to get routes, model binders etc. wired up correctly.

For a more structures approach to compose the application of separate modules, you may want to look into [portable areas](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/). This is an extension to ASP.NET MVC that allows you to package the entire module (including views, css, js etc.) into a single assembly.

Comment: ok, so i need a custom logic for something that i already have in webfoms?

Comment: Only if you use custom routes, custom model binders or dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you have to work on the title of the post, it does not match the content of the post.

In asp.net mvc u can choose to deploy only what changed. I.e. If you only changed the .cshtml file, then you can just replace it with the file in production. However if you change any controller class (C#/Vb code), then you will have to upload the web project dll file too so that this new changes are available in the production env